# What is UN doing about Ukrainian crisis?

Tags: ukraine, russian-federation

What is UN doing about the Ukrainian crisis?

Comment: at the moment, it appears they are showing concern and planning meetings https://www.google.com/search?q=UN+Ukraine&tbm=nws

Comment: The UN won't do anything with any real impact about this. Russia has veto power and will use it.

Comment: @Ryathal I'd go one step further and say that UN is especially designed so that it *can't* do anything against one of the permanent 5 security council members; so one shouldn't expect anything. The system is designed so that disputes like this must be resolved outside of UN.

Comment: @DA. Ah, so they are doing what they always do.

Comment: That sounds like the start of a good answer @Peteris.

Comment: @YannisRizos - I have a perfect solution for Ukraine. Grab some Palestinian refugees and resettle them in Crymea and Eastern Ukraine. It will immediately become a major concern for UN.

Comment: @YannisRizos in that the UN doesn't tend to rush to invade countries, I suppose so.